# Json.Deserialize does not work on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, json, unity-game-engine

```
 var dict = Json.Deserialize(text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

this line produces a good and working dictionary when I run it on my pc and on a Mac but when I run it on the Ipad running iOS 8.3 the dict is null. text is just the responce string I'm getting from a WWW call. I'm using facebook's MiniJson implementation in my unity game. Any ideas , is it something to do with reflection( have had problems like this in the past).

Comment: Assuming there's no exception, try removing the cast and seeing what is actually returned.  It might not be `Dictionary<string, object>` but it could be something other than `null`.  You should also verify that `text` is as you expect.

Comment: @Charles Mager . Deserialize returns a object. How can I see what is returned without casting it to something? Also I verified that the response text is empty. But why is it empty on the Ipad and good on other devices?

Comment: `GetType` or mouse over it in the debugger. Though if `text` is empty then it probably is `null`. Your issue isn't with deserialisation.

Comment: @ Charles Mager you are right. I just fixed. turns out I did not request some data I need from facebook when the user was already logged into fb but the app wasnt started, hence the nulls and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. The problem was in a entirely different place. JSON works fine on ios.